# 403 error when access controller in subfolder (CodeIgniter)

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, controller, http-status-code-403, subdirectory

This is my application skeleton:

```
application
    controllers
        backend
            [backend_controllers_here]
        [frontend_controllers_here]
    models
        [shared_models_for_both_backend_and_frontend]
    views
        backend
            [backend_views_here]
        [frontend_views_here]
    ...
system
index.php
.htaccess
```

This is my .htaccess file content:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Set the default file for indexes
# DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # activate URL rewriting
    RewriteEngine on

    # do not rewrite links to the documentation, assets and public files
    RewriteCond $1 !^(images|assets|uploads|captcha)

    # do not rewrite for php files in the document root, robots.txt or the maintenance page
    RewriteCond $1 !^([^\..]+\.php|robots\.txt)

    # but rewrite everything else

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.

    ErrorDocument 404 index.php

</IfModule>
```

It's nothing wrong when I type on address-bar something like these (for frontend):

- mysite.local
- mysite.local/index.php
- mysite.local/index.php/frontend_controller
- mysite.local/frontend_controller

But for backend I had a **403 error** when try to access:

- mysite.local/backend
- mysite.local/backend/some_backend_controller

However, with index.php in URL everything is fine.

- mysite.local/index.php/backend
- mysite.local/index.php/backend/some_backend_controller

Am I missing something here?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

check the permission for the backend folder. it maybe prevents the webserver from reading the actual content of the directory.
The permission should allow reading for everyone

Comment: This is obviously not the issue since it works with index.php. It's probably an issue with the url rewriting rules which don't expect this use case.

Answer (score -2):

What does your config/routes.php look like? Might try something like this:

```
$route['backend'] = "backend/controller/method";
```